# using sed to cut a part of file

Tags: bash, sed

cat /opt/inventory.txt

```
###################################################################################
Begin_detail_of 5678
Request_No of the activity is 5678
testProject
Requester of the project is xyz
xyz@test.com
End_of 5678
####################################################################################
###################################################################################
Begin_detail_of 1234
Request_No of the activity is 1234
testProject
Requester of the project is xyz
xyz@test.com
End_of 1234
####################################################################################
```

When I use the number 1234 as below I get expected output as below

```
cat /opt/inventory.txt | sed -n -e '/Begin_detail_of\ 5678/,$p' | sed -e '/End_of\ 5678/,$d'
Begin_detail_of 5678
Request_No of the activity is 5678
testProject
Requester of the project is xyz
xyz@test.com
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

But when I substitute the number with variable output is not as expected as below

```
[root@centoo script]# export num=5678
[root@centoo script]# echo $num
5678
[root@centoo script]# cat /opt/inventory.txt | sed -n -e '/Begin_detail_of\ $num/,$p' | sed -e '/End_of\ $num/,$d'
[root@centoo script]#
```

Please help to solve the issue.

Comment: using double quotes instead single when using variables is often solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need 2 sed commands and make sure to use double quotes while using a shell variable in expression. You can do this in same `sed` like this:

```
num=5678
sed -n "/Begin_detail_of $num/,/End_of $num/{/End_of $num/d;p;}" file
Begin_detail_of 5678
Request_No of the activity is 5678
testProject
Requester of the project is xyz
xyz@test.com
```

Comment: Thank you very much Anubhav - Barani

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tool, sed is not for anything that spans multiple lines. Just use the standard UNIX text processing tool, awk. Here's GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ gawk -v tgt='5678' -v RS='#+\n' -v ORS= '$0~"Begin_detail_of "tgt"\n"' file
Begin_detail_of 5678
Request_No of the activity is 5678
testProject
Requester of the project is xyz
xyz@test.com
End_of 5678

$ gawk -v tgt='1234' -v RS='#+\n' -v ORS= '$0~"Begin_detail_of "tgt"\n"' file
Begin_detail_of 1234
Request_No of the activity is 1234
testProject
Requester of the project is xyz
xyz@test.com
End_of 1234
```

and if you want to remove the first and last lines:

```
$ gawk -v tgt='5678' -v RS='End_of[^\n]+\n#+\n' -v ORS= 'sub("#+\nBegin_detail_of "tgt"\n","")' file
Request_No of the activity is 5678
testProject
Requester of the project is xyz
xyz@test.com

$ gawk -v tgt='1234' -v RS='End_of[^\n]+\n#+\n' -v ORS= 'sub("#+\nBegin_detail_of "tgt"\n","")' file
Request_No of the activity is 1234
testProject
Requester of the project is xyz
xyz@test.com
```

Whatever you want to do is brief and trivial since this is what awk is designed to do.

Comment: You're welcome. FYI besides the obvious problem with duplicating the end condition, the sed solution you accepted will fail in bizarre ways given various contents of your shell variables.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v RS="###################################################################################" /"End_of $num"/ file
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable(some word starts with a $) in double quotes will be sustituted to it's content while one in single quotes will not. It's the feature of shell. So if you want to generate sed commands dynamically, just use single quotes.

Comment: Sure Nano I will follow it. Thanks - Barani